# Двумерный массив из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Допустим в переменную $odin попадает значение из одного столбца, в $dva попадает значение из другого столбца этой же таблицы. $id - это столбец id этой же таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

причем ID может принимать значения не по порядку, но никогда не повторяется в таблице.

Есть задача вывести данные из полей БД в массив, ниже пример(чтобы получилось так):

```
$links = array (
    $id => array ($odin,$dva),
    $id => array ($odin,$dva),
    $id => array ($odin,$dva)
);
```

Вроде как двумерный массив
и тд... количество строк не имеет значение(оно постоянно будет пополняться)

Как можно сделать такой массив...и как потом пользоваться значениями из него...

Comment: Ваш вопрос полностью вырван из контекста. Из вашей формулировки вопроса можно понять только следующее. У вас отсутствует представление о работе реляционной модели базы данных и языке SQL, так же отсутствует приведенная схема таблицы и методы выборки данных средствами PHP.

Comment: *как можно сделать такой массив* - `$links[] = [0,1];`

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с базой данных в РНР служит класс PDO.

Для получения двумерного массива из результатов запроса служит метод `fetchAll()`.

Для получения двумерного массива, индексированного уникальным полем, служит метод `fetchAll()` в режиме [FETCH_UNIQUE](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#unique):

```
$links = $pdo->query('SELECT id, odin, dva FROM links')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

вернет массив в нужном формате.